How to insert a seal with a certificate into a PDF file so that the image of seal does not cover the text?(C#)
Can't find a way to set a seal image beneath text or table of document.
I tried to use examples from
PdfPadesSigner(https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/advanced-examples-for-signaturefieldappearance) and
PdfSigner(https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/how-to-use-a-digital-signing-service-dss-such-as-g#HowtouseaDigitalSigningService(DSS)suchasGlobalSign,withiText-Examplecode),
but all of them attach a solid image on the text, so that other users can't recognize what text covered by that seal's image.
This confused me a long time. I know it is possible to change opacity of signature image, but I don't want to change that. I wonder is there a way to just let that image stamped beneath document's texts.
The style I want is text on the red star:

The style iText generates is text beneath the red star:


What you originally wanted, a genuine signature appearance that is underneath (along the z axis) the existing page content, is not possible: The genuine signature appearance is the appearance of a widget annotation of the signature field in question, and annotations always are painted over the existing page content, not beneath it.
What you can do, is working with transparency. This can mean changing the image alpha value or using a different blend mode. But you already said you prefer not to go that road.
Another alternative is not using the genuine signature appearance at all but instead adding the image to the static page content.
This is the approach you used in your answer; that implementation has a shortcoming, though: it only keeps the static content of the original page and otherwise generates a new page from it. This in turn means that any existing dynamic page content (annotations, in particular form field widgets; link targets; ...) is lost.
You can prevent this by instead adding the image to the existing page content using PdfPage.newContentStreamBefore (to make the addition go underneath).
But there still are issues: On one hand there are PDFs in which the existing content starts with filling the whole page area with white color; this obviously would cover your image. And on the other hand, if the PDF already has previous signatures, you will break those signatures because changing the static page content of signed PDFs is not allowed.

I found a way to combine picture and document.
    using (PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(src))
{
    using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("D:\\output.pdf"))
    {
        using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader2, writer))
        {
            PdfPage ThePageNeedToSeal = pdfDoc.GetPage(1);
            PdfPage NewPage =pdfDoc.AddNewPage(1);
            ImageData pdfImage = ImageDataFactory.Create("D:\\Stamp_Picture.png");
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(NewPage);
            canvas.AddImageAt(pdfImage,0,0,true);
            PdfFormXObject page = new PdfFormXObject(ThePageNeedToSeal);
            canvas.AddXObject(page);
            pdfDoc.Close();
        }
    }
}

And then call that official demo without signature image. It seems takes a long way round, maybe there is simpler method.
——————————————————————————————————————
2024-06-05 update
I can use PdfExtGState.BM_MULTIPLY to mix image with document, I wonder if everyelse already known that.
PdfCanvas over = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.GetPage(1));
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(StampPath);
over.SaveState();
PdfExtGState gs1 = new PdfExtGState().SetBlendMode(PdfExtGState.BM_MULTIPLY);
over.SetExtGState(gs1);
over.AddImageFittedIntoRectangle(imageData, new Rectangle(BottomLocation.GetX(), 120, 120, 120), true);
over.RestoreState();

This seems to be the shortest way.
